# How do I change the constructor code in SWIG generated CSHARP file

Tags: c#, c++, constructor, swig

I have a C++ DLL for which I have generated C# code using SWIG tool. The intermediary class has the following method (assuming the module name is MyModule) in the PINVOKE.cs file:

```
static MyModulePINVOKE() 
{
    ...
}
```

I want to perform a module initialization which can be done in SWIG using `%init%` keyword but that keyword is not available for C#. [See the following post for details](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/Behavior-of-init-for-C-td6541.html). I followed the instructions in the post and able to do what I want but I want my code to run in the PINVOKE class constructor so I am looking for a way to insert code into the constructor.

Googled and found the *csconstruct* keyword but not sure how to use it. The following snippet does not give desired results. Any ideas what could be wrong here:

```
%typemap(csconstruct, excode=SWIGEXCODE) SWIGTYPE
%{
    ...
%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. The solution is to define **SWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR** preprocessor in the SWIG command line:

```
SWIG.EXE -Wall -DSWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR -c++ -csharp ...
```

This will tell SWIG NOT to generate the default static constructor in the intermediary class. Then use the following code in SWIG interface file to add a custom constructor:

```
%pragma(csharp) imclasscode=%{
    static $imclassname()
    {
      ... // do something for initialization
    }
%}
```